# Can you use an infinite loop to run a program continuously using Java?

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I have a question that I have researched that I did not find any compelling answers to. If you want to run a program in a loop every 2 hours or so, and of course, I know that anyone can use windows scheduler or something like that, will running the program in an infinite loop and using the "continue" statement every 2 hours or so prevent it from breaking (StackOverflow)?

Comment: If you do that in a loop and not with recursive calls there will be no stack that overflows. Having said that, I'd go with the OS scheduler/cron/whatever.

Comment: Two difficulties with a loop method. (a) If it dies, or the system reboots, it needs to get restarted (assuming anybody notices). (b) If it is active for a significant time during each cycle, the start time progressively drifts. A scheduler solves both of these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Something simple/primitive like this will get you started:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) 
    while (true) {
        try {
            // do something
            Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(2));
        } catch Exception e {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can do this. But there are multiple ways to do it much better. First even if you want to do infinite loop do it in a separate thread. But the simplest and standard way to do something like this is to write some class that implements [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface, place your "do something" code into its method `run()` and use [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to schedule your task for every 2 hours. The `ScheduledExecutorService` you can get from [Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(int corePoolSize)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool-int-) method. On a side note, There is a Open source library (written by me) that can simplify sleep delay code for you instead of

```
try {
    // do something
    Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(2));
} catch Exception e {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

you can just write something like this:

```
private static final TimeInterval TWO_HOURS = new TimeInterval(2L, TimeUnit.HOURS);
...
//Do something
TimeUtils.sleepFor(TWO_HOURS);
```

The Exception is handled inside. Here is the Javadoc for [TimeUtils](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/TimeUtils.html) class. The library is called MgntUtils and could be taken as [Mavien Artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc)