# Scheduling recurring tasks with java

Tags: java

I am working on a program that logins into a website. It obtains some values and then does certain clicks on the website every 135 minutes or so. value, "obtained_value" is read from the website, which is decremented by some value each click the program makes. I want to run the program till the  obtained value is less than 10. Once that happens, I want to pause the program till target time is reached and restart the clicking cycle. I want to do this everytime the target time is reached. I implemented this logic in the following code, but my code remains sleep after target time is reached, instead of restarting the loop. How can I fix this?

```
        while (true) {
        var remainder = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                "/html/body/uni-app/uni-page/uni-page-wrapper/uni-page-body/uni-view/uni-view[3]/uni-view[2]/uni-view[2]")).getText();
        var remaining = Double.parseDouble(remainder);
        
        var last_time = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                "/html/body/uni-app/uni-page/uni-page-wrapper/uni-page-body/uni-view/uni-view[5]/uni-view[3]/uni-view[1]")).getText();

        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        date.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(last_time)); // Parse into Date object
        date.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2022);
        var obtained_value = date.getTime().getTime();

        long current_time = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(); // Get time now
        long target_time = obtained_value + 7920000;
        long millis = target_time - System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (millis <= 0) {
            if (remaining > 5) {
                driver.findElement(By.className("orderBtn")).click();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                Thread.sleep(6000);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/uni-app/uni-page/uni-page-wrapper/uni-page-body/uni-view/uni-view[7]/uni-view/uni-view/uni-view[6]/uni-button[2]")).click();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                Thread.sleep(6000);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/uni-app/uni-page/uni-page-wrapper/uni-page-body/uni-view/uni-view[8]/uni-view/uni-view/uni-button")).click();
            }
        }
        try {
           if(millis > 0)
              Thread.sleep(millis);
            else
                continue;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

It makes sense that the code breaks after it reaches the specified time, since Thread.sleep does not accept negative values, but I do not know how to get around this error at the moment. How can resume the loop everytime Thread.sleep(millis) is reached? At the momement, the program remains sleep even after target time is reached.

Comment: Why don't you use the Timer class? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very similar to this one: [can you use infinite loop to run a program continuesly using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72211761/can-you-use-infinite-loop-to-run-a-program-continuesly-using-java/72212286#72212286). The main point is to schedule reoccurring task you should use [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) that you can obtain from [Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(int corePoolSize)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool-int-) medthod. Once you notice that obtained value is less than 10 you should shutdown your `ScheduledExecutorService` and create a new one with wich you can schedule yourr task to start at your appointed time with your desired intervals.

Comment: True. How would you do that? I am sorry I am newbie to this. @Michael Gantman

Comment: ScheduledExecutorService has a shutdown method. Your Runnable should have a reference to you ScheduledExecutorService and once your value is below the threshold invoke shutdown on your old ScheduledExecutorService and create a new one with the scheduling from new time

Comment: I have tried to follow those steps, but nothing is working. Will you be so kind to share the code the solution? @Michael Gantman

Comment: I don't have the ready made code. I could write it, but that's not the point of this site. here you can ask about specific problems and solutions. Here I gave you the idea how to implement the solution but the implementation is up to you. Read up on use of   ScheduledExecutorService